# Formally introducing yourself in an email

Tags: formality, email

I am composing an email to a work associate who I have never had any dealings with before. I'm struggling to think of a *formal* yet *succinct* way of introducing myself.

In person, I would probably say:

> "Pleased to meet you"

But this feels wrong because I am not actually meeting him- I'm just sending an email.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Something like this?

> Dear Mr Jones,
>
> I'm John Smith, a code monkey, and I work with Phillip in the IT pit.
>   He suggested that you might be able to help me hack into Accounts and
>   give myself a raise.
>
> It would really help me in my new project - *P0232 - Theft for Fun and Profit*.
>
> I'm free for the rest of the day because I'm pulling a sickie.
>
> Boomshanka,
>
> David

Comment: Wow. You didn't just do the introduction. You wrote my whole email for me! Thanks!

Comment: +1 Entertaining, yet correct : you included the introduction (who put you in contact with them), your role, and your purpose. Rather than a polite boilerplate, an introductory email requires that you start with why they should not hit the spam button.

Comment: Perhaps add: "May the seed of your loin be fruitful in the belly of your woman" and complete the subtle reference ;

Comment: +1, although I would ditch the salutation line. They are as superflous in emails as they are in StackExchange questions.

Comment: What's the point of giving your name when it is actually already available in the `From` field? Can't you write "Dear Mr Jones, I'm a code monkey, and I work..."

Comment: Yes, rds, you're probably correct.

Comment: Well you may want to say `I'm John Smith, aka David,...`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

> Dear Mr Smith,
>
> my name is Neo, and as I got your email address from Mr Morpheus
>   without having met you in person before, please allow me to introduce
>   myself first.
>
> My profession is that of a programmer. I have expert knowledge in
>   search engines and one of my latest project involved developing my own
>   search engine for automatic web page scraping and later text
>   classifaction and rating using a semi-autonomous text analysis agent.
>
> ...
>
> I have learned from Mr Morpheus that you are currently involved in a
>   project dealing with similar issues. Therefore, I would like to offer
>   my expertise to you.
>
> If you are interested, do not hesitate to call me at +1 2317 424242.
>
> Sincerely yours
>
> Neo Anderson

Comment: It's formal (and funny), but not very succinct.

Comment: Well, formal speech is usually longer than normal speech because you spend extra effort on being formal - which requires more words. Unlike Japanese, where you change the ending of a verb and you're formal, English doesn't have a function like that. Most European languages implement formalty by using a different choice of words and a more elaborate, extended way of saying the same thing.